# How to retrieve data from a POST and redirect based on that data

Tags: python, flask, twilio

Been stuck with this all day. I think I figured out how to fetch the data I need from the POST but don't know how to send to another route and hangup or terminate anything else.

What I've been trying to work with right now, but it's not working.

```
@app.route("/recieve", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def recieve():
    Human = request.get_data('AnsweredBy')
    if Human == human:
        return redirect(url_for('main'))

    else Human == machine_start:
        return str(resp)
```

Need to extract `AnsweredBy=machine_start` and either hangup the call or send to another route.

```
POST /main HTTP/1.1
Host: clip.ngrok.io
User-Agent: TwilioProxy/1.1
Content-Length: 551
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
I-Twilio-Idempotency-Token: clip
Referer: https://clipngrok.io/main
X-Forwarded-For: clip
X-Forwarded-Proto: https
X-Home-Region: us1
X-Twilio-Signature: e7Of/MiuQe3x+ymbPLk3Mwr4hJM=
Accept-Encoding: gzip

AccountSid=Clip1&AnsweredBy=machine_start&ApiVersion=2010-04-01&CallSid=Clip&CallStatus=in-progress&Called=%clip&CalledCity=CAPE+GIRARDEAU&CalledCountry=US&CalledState=MO&CalledZip=63780&Caller=%clip&CallerCity=VENTURA&CallerCountry=US&CallerState=CA&CallerZip=93001&Direction=outbound-api&From=%clip&FromCity=VENTURA&FromCountry=US&FromState=CA&FromZip=93001&MachineDetectionDuration=5676&To=%clip&ToCity=CAPE+GIRARDEAU&ToCountry=US&ToState=MO&ToZip=63780
```

Comment: It seems that you're comparing a bytestring with a string. 
Use `request.get_data('AnsweredBy', as_text=True)` to return the value from the form data as a decoded unicode string for comparison

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using

```
is_human = request.form.get('AnsweredBy')

    if is_human == 'human':
```